# WSO2IS Facebook federation

Tags: wso2-identity-server

It's possible to use facebook info, and get some information in the local database in the userinhfo api?

Let'me explain, I get name and mail from facebook claim, and I want the userinfo api returns that information, and local information in the local user store.

Becouse I have the user facebook email provisioned in the secondary user store, if the user is in the PRIMARY user store, userinfo works perfectly, there are some way to work with secondary user store. And my secondary user store is a custom implementation of jdbc user store.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do. What you can do is authenticate the user using wso2 IS. Since you use custom implementation, the claim mapping should be done accordingly. If the claims are not there [create custom claims](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider).
Try to use those claims to map the Facebook user information

Or you may want to use facebook SDK to get user information.